# How to use Incremental Backup

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database at a remote server that gets updated once in a while and what i normally do to transfer it to my locale machine is to

```
mysql -u root -padmin databasename > backup.sql
```

Then on the workbench of my local machine i just delete the old database and import this new database.

I usually did this because updates came in once a month. So i wasn't bothered. But now the data has gotten pretty big and i can't afford to do this anymore. I just thought there is a better approach so i looked into incremental backups but i don't quite get it. In my situation, how will i use incremental backups ? So that in the remote server i only backup the latest changes in the remote database then import to my local database ?

Comment: Interesting question, I've studied part of it and it has quite a lot of problems: Deleted rows, updated data, alter tables..., I'm looking forward for someone that knows a way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using InnoDB, the percona guys can help you with xtrabackup: http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup
It has incremental options and also restores quickly.  I'm not sure it supports myisam (since that engine is not ACID).

We use it at work to great effect.